# Crashing on deserializing list from Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have a model which contains a list.

```
class Group {
   List<String> members;
   // Other fields
}
```

I'm inserting the whole model in Firebase using `databaseRef.setValue(group)`. Now it's being inserted properly in firebase but the problem arise when I try to add any new value in `members` field.

I'm using `membersRef.push().setValue("newMember@gmail.com")` to add new field in members list on firebase.

When `Group` object was created initially Firebase used "0", "1", etc as key but when I push() it creates a unique String as key.

I'm creating the Java object back using this code:

```
groupReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
     @Override
     public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
         Group group = dataSnapshot.getValue(Group.class);
     }

     @Override
     public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

     }
});
```

Now the problem is when creating the `Group` class back from Firebase it tries to convert the `members` field in a `List` because it's key start from 0 but after some iteration there is a `String` key (something like "-KjTzYGRDZN99rBZfPDF") so it crashes trying to convert it to `List`.

My Firebase object looks something like this:

```
Group
|-----members
         |----0: "abc@gmail.com"
         |-----KjTzYGRDZN99rBZfPDF: "def@gmail.com"
```

I'm confused how do I solve this problem. How do I tell firebase to use unique key for List instead of 0, 1, 2, etc?

Answer (score 0):

use a `HashMap` instead of `List`. then when storing the `group` object on firebase, make sure the `hashmap` is empty. Now, you can migrate to the `membersRef` and put all the values you want using a loop with `push()` and `setValue()` in subsequent code.